# Jack in the pulpit? Italian arum?

Tags: identification

This was found along the path in Edgewood Park, San Carlos, CA.
[image]  There were a line of them, so I think they were planted.  As Jack in the pulpit is native, I would suspect that, but the pictures I see have three prominent leaves.

Answer (score 3):

It is one of the *Arum*. It is difficult to distinguish the *Arum maculatum* and *Arum italicum* from this plant.

There is no clear white spot on the leaves (which would clearly define this plant as the italic species, but the spatula is (still) yellow (also a characteristic of italic species, but from time to time found also on the common species).

So if with time thee spatula will become violet to brown, I would say *Arum maculatum*. In the other case, I would search for nearby plants or I would not bet in a species.

Note: many floras put some characteristics (e.g. black points, veins, direction of the lower spike, ...), but these are not really consistent (but maybe inside a delimited region).

Comment: Oh by the way all the plants in this family are highly poisonous! so wash your hands after handling- oh and this one has red berries in autumn which are very juicy looking for children!